# JS: Displaying message according to day of the week

Tags: javascript, getdate

Pulling my hair out trying to figure this out. I'd like to display a message according to the day of the week via innerHTML. I've looked at countless similar issues here and elsewhere, but nothing seems to be working. I've tried various alterations of the if statements, but nothing is successful. Everything I try returns a "day is not defined" error.

Thanks in advance.

(Also, likely relevant: I'm new to Javascript)

JS:

```
function checkTime(i) {
  if (i < 10) {
    i = "0" + i;
  }
  return i;
}
function startTime() {
  var today = new Date();
  var weekday = new Array(7);
  weekday[0] = "Sun";
  weekday[1] = "Mon";
  weekday[2] = "Tues";
  weekday[3] = "Weds";
  weekday[4] = "Thurs";
  weekday[5] = "Fri";
  weekday[6] = "Sat";
  var day = weekday[today.getDay()];
  var h = today.getHours();
  var m = today.getMinutes();
  var s = today.getSeconds();
  var month = new Array(12);
    month[0] = "Jan";
    month[1] = "Feb";
    month[2] = "March";
    month[3] = "April";
    month[4] = "May";
    month[5] = "June";
    month[6] = "July";
    month[7] = "Aug";
    month[8] = "Sept";
    month[9] = "Oct";
    month[10] = "Nov";
    month[11] = "Dec";
    var currentMonth = month[today.getMonth()];
  var year = today.getFullYear();   
  // add a zero in front of numbers<10
  h = checkTime(h);
  m = checkTime(m);
  s = checkTime(s); 
  document.getElementById('currentTime').innerHTML = day + " " + h + ":" + m + ":" + s; 
  t = setTimeout(function() {
    startTime()
  }, 500);
}
startTime();
if (day == "Fri") {
    document.getElementById("timeText").innerHTML = "Nearly the weekend!";
} else if (day == "Sat") {
    document.getElementById("timeText").innerHTML = "It's Beer O'Clock";
} else {
    document.getElementById("timeText").innerHTML = "JS Failed";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`day` is a local variable of the `startTime` function. It's not available outside that function, and you're trying to access it in `if (day == "Fri")`. Move that if-else statement inside `startTime()` and it should work.

Comment: Thank you so much! I wish I would have come here 24 hours ago lol

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the `day` variable. It was declared inside `startTime` function so it will not be accessible in the `if` statement

```js
var day = '';

function checkTime(i) {
  if (i < 10) {
    i = "0" + i;
  }
  return i;
}

function startTime() {
  var today = new Date();
  var weekday = new Array(7);
  weekday[0] = "Sun";
  weekday[1] = "Mon";
  weekday[2] = "Tues";
  weekday[3] = "Weds";
  weekday[4] = "Thurs";
  weekday[5] = "Fri";
  weekday[6] = "Sat";
  day = weekday[today.getDay()];
  var h = today.getHours();
  var m = today.getMinutes();
  var s = today.getSeconds();
  var month = new Array(12);
  month[0] = "Jan";
  month[1] = "Feb";
  month[2] = "March";
  month[3] = "April";
  month[4] = "May";
  month[5] = "June";
  month[6] = "July";
  month[7] = "Aug";
  month[8] = "Sept";
  month[9] = "Oct";
  month[10] = "Nov";
  month[11] = "Dec";
  var currentMonth = month[today.getMonth()];
  var year = today.getFullYear();
  // add a zero in front of numbers<10
  h = checkTime(h);
  m = checkTime(m);
  s = checkTime(s);
  document.getElementById('currentTime').innerHTML = day + " " + h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
  t = setTimeout(function() {
    startTime()
  }, 500);
}
startTime();
if (day == "Fri") {
  document.getElementById("timeText").innerHTML = "Nearly the weekend!";
} else if (day == "Sat") {
  document.getElementById("timeText").innerHTML = "It's Beer O'Clock";
} else {
  document.getElementById("timeText").innerHTML = "JS Failed";
}
```

```html
<div id="currentTime"></div>
<div id="timeText"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me with a few adjustments

```js
function checkTime(i) {
  if (i < 10) {
    i = "0" + i;
  }
  return i;
}
function startTime() {
  var today = new Date();
  var weekday = new Array(7);
  weekday[0] = "Sun";
  weekday[1] = "Mon";
  weekday[2] = "Tues";
  weekday[3] = "Weds";
  weekday[4] = "Thurs";
  weekday[5] = "Fri";
  weekday[6] = "Sat";
  var day = weekday[today.getDay()];
  var h = today.getHours();
  var m = today.getMinutes();
  var s = today.getSeconds();
  var month = new Array(12);
 month[0] = "Jan";
 month[1] = "Feb";
 month[2] = "March";
 month[3] = "April";
 month[4] = "May";
 month[5] = "June";
 month[6] = "July";
 month[7] = "Aug";
 month[8] = "Sept";
 month[9] = "Oct";
 month[10] = "Nov";
 month[11] = "Dec";
 var currentMonth = month[today.getMonth()];
  var year = today.getFullYear(); 
  // add a zero in front of numbers<10
  h = checkTime(h);
  m = checkTime(m);
  s = checkTime(s); 
  document.getElementById('currentTime').innerHTML = day + " " + h + ":" + m + ":" + s; 
  
  if (day == "Fri") {
 document.getElementById("timeText").innerHTML = "Nearly the weekend!";
} else if (day == "Sat") {
 document.getElementById("timeText").innerHTML = "It's Beer O'Clock";
} else {
 document.getElementById("timeText").innerHTML = "JS Failed";
}
}
startTime();
```

```html
<div id="currentTime"></div>
<div id="timeText"></div>
```